# Can I hide schemas in the schema panel in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have many schemas in MySQL server and am using MySQL Workbench to administer. Is there a method to hide the schemas I'm not currently using?

Comment: usual the database you are currently using  are open, so that you can access everything quite easy, the others are closed

Comment: They are closed bu they're still listed making it difficult to find one specific DB when there are 20 or so DBs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually a possibility

Use the search and only the wanted schemes are visible

[image]